# Sphinx inline footnotes?

Tags: python-sphinx

Sphinx currently outputs footnotes at the end of a document, but for HTML display it seems like there might be better options.

Is there a way for it to output footnotes as popups inline, i.e. displaying the footnote in a floating box when the callout is clicked on?

Comment: I don't think there is...  why not submit a feature request?

Comment: See if this is starting to be what you want...

https://gist.github.com/tk0miya/2507585

Comment: i've opened an issue mentioning the idea: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3974